# Display flickering issue and restart after upgrade

Tags: kernel, updates, 22.04, display

I recently got an update of linux-image-generic 5.15.0.86.83. After updating screen starts flickering badly any time after starting the system and sometime restarts the system. I can boot the system using previous version installed linux-image-5.15.0-84-generic 5.15.0-84.93. I have tried reinstalling linux-image-generic 5.15.0.86.83, but it didn't work.
Below is my configuration.

[image: Screenshot-from-2023-10-10-09-22-50.png]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I've downgraded to version 5.15.0-84 and marked it 'hold' waiting for futurs versions.

1. reboot with previous version (for me 5.15.0-84) :
   grub menu + advanced options.
2. reinstall version 5.15.0-79 and 5.15.0-83 :
   apt install --reinstall linux-image-5.15.0-79-generic linux-image-5.15.0-83-generic
3. remove version 5.15.0-86 :
   apt purge linux-image-5.15.0-86-*; apt autoremove
4. reboot with previous version (for me 5.15.0-84) :
   grub menu + advanced options.
5. mark 'hold' version 5.15.0-84 :
   apt-mark hold linux-image-5.15.0-84-generic

WARNING : Never remove the running version, reboot on other version before.